# How to properly save and use my template [e.g. for colors]?

Tags: flutter, templates, dart, styles

The way I currently save my design template (colors, constraints, sizes...) in flutter projects is by creating a file called: `style_constants.dart` in `lib/theme/` This is for instance how the file could look like:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color colorShade1 = Color(0xFFEFF0F2);
const Color colorShade2 = Color(0xFF777777);
const Color colorShade3 = Color(0xFF424242);
const Color colorShade4 = Color(0xFF4B4935);
const Color colorShade5 = Color(0xFF3D2916);
const Color colorShade6 = Color(0xFF1D1C0A);

const Color colorBackground = Color(0xFF101A24);
const Color colorPrimary1 = Color(0xFFCC9757);
const Color colorRed = Color(0xFFEB5757);

// TabBar
const double kTabIconHeight = 28;

// CTA
const double kCtaHeight = 52;
const double kCtaWidth = 358;
const Color colorCtaBackground = Colors.white;
const TextStyle ktsCta = TextStyle(color: colorRed, fontSize: 19, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700);
```

The way I'm doing it works, HOWEVER it is most probably NOT the best way to do it. I found on the official [dart page](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-defining-a-class-that-contains-only-static-members) that it would be better to do it this way:

```dart
class Color {
  static const red = '#f00';
  static const green = '#0f0';
  static const blue = '#00f';
  static const black = '#000';
  static const white = '#fff';
}
```

I tried to incorporate it but somehow did NOT work. Can you please show me the best-practice in terms of saving your own design a.k.a. CSS template?

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 issues with your way of implementing your `Color` class. First is that your class has the same typo as the material `Color` from flutter which might cause conflicts when adding it into a file where the package `material.dart` is also imported. The second one is more of a personal taste, I am not a big fan of using HEX color format as flutter `Color` constructor takes an int as its parameter. On my projects I am saving my colors like this:

```dart
class MyColors {
   static const someRed = Color(0xFFFF6666);
   static const someGreen = Color(0xFF24B356);
   // etc...
}
```

The conversion from HEX to int is quite easy, you only need to replace the `#` by `0xFF`. For example a color `static const hexSomeBlue = "#8d91b8";` will became `static const someBlue = Color(0xFF8d91b8);`

Comment: what typo do you mean?

Comment: You named your class `Color` which is the same name as the class `Color` from flutter.

Comment: Aah, I see... thanks but I was just referencing and copying the flutter docs, it's them who propose doing it that way. Check it out for yourself if you want to: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-defining-a-class-that-contains-only-static-members That's exactly why I was confused by too

Comment: I see, and as they've said in the doc you linked you should try to avoid name collision either by giving it a more precise name or by moving it inside a library and importing it with a prefix.

Comment: I'm certainly no expert but I don't think that's what they recommend, esp. in this case. It's actually them who recommend naming the class Color. In other parts of the docs they say "If you’re worried about name collisions, give it a more precise name or move it to a separate library that can be imported with a prefix." so it's not them that recommend it's more if users are worried about that...